# How to modify and reuse parts of a tree defined in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I have defined a tree using the `pic` property for later reuse, e.g. the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset {
  my tree/.pic = {
    \node (4){4}
    child { node (5){5}
      child { node (15){15} }
      child { node (9){9} }
    }
    child { node (8){8}
      child { node (20){20} }
      child { node (10){10} }
    }
    ;
  },
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=35mm, level distance=1cm},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=17mm, level distance=1cm},
  level 3/.style={sibling distance=10mm, level distance=1cm},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic{my tree};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which yields

[image: mwe tree]

I would now like in another `tikzpicture` environment to redraw `my tree` but with  children added to some nodes, e.g. the red nodes below

[image: mwe tree redrawn with desired leaves]

or with some nodes inserted, e.g. the red node below
[image]

without having to completely redefine the tree.

Can this be achieved in TikZ? And if so, how?

Comment: Do you really think it's worthwhile writing an elaborate macro for this, which can be done so quickly with copy and paste?

Comment: Also, use `forest` for these types of trees rather than the standard TikZ methods. The syntax is drastically simpler, and the trees are automatically sized.

Comment: @marmot Copy and paste is messy and prone to errors. The above is just a MWE. My actual tree is larger.

Comment: Well, my macros are even more messy ;-)

Comment: @AlanMunn I agree about `forest`. but stick to `tikz` because `AucTeX` indents `tikz` properly but not `forest` which affects readability. I do not now enough `elisp` to write proper indentation for `forest` in `AucTeX`. This is a known issue, https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17396/indentation-in-square-brackets.

Comment: @AlanMunn Does anything indent it correctly? Kile doesn't, for sure. I can't imagine coding this from scratch will be easier than manually formatting a few lines of Forest code, anyway.

Comment: @cfr Indentation schmindentation! All my trees are on single lines. :D

Comment: @AlanMunn Seriously? You don't get confused doing it that way? I sometimes put them on a single line when I've finished, though.

Comment: @wsaleem The Q&A you linked has an answer which claims it solves the problem. Doesn't it work? (I wouldn't know - never use `emacs`.)

Comment: @cfr No, in linguistics we use bracketed structures a lot anyway to save space (although not full bracketings) so I'm really accustomed to reading and writing structures that way.

Comment: @AlanMunn Ah, I see. That makes me feel a bit less dumb, then :-).

Answer (score 4):

Excuse my saying so, but not using Forest because your editor can't indent it automatically is bonkers. I don't know if any editor indents it correctly - certainly mine does not - but Forest trees are still more readable than Ti*k*Z's verbose equivalents and, even if they were not, sacrificing power and flexibility for a smidgen of auto-formatting is just mad. You'll easily spend more time hacking a solution from scratch than you would formatting small bits of your source by hand.

Anyway, Forest is **the** way to do this. There just isn't another approach which makes any kind of sense here. (Lua can probably do it, too, but it won't provide the ready-made recipes Forest gives you out-of-the-box.)

Here's a Forest solution for an ungrateful world.

First, we set up a style, `my tree`, which defines our base tree. This takes a single, optional value, which can be used to specify code for modifying the tree.

```
\forestset{
  my tree/.style={
    delay={
      !r.replace by={[4, #1 [5[15][9]][8[20][10]]]},
    },
  },
}
```

Then we can produce the base tree with

```
\Forest{
  my tree,
  []
}
```

the first modified tree with

```
\Forest{
  my tree={
    before typesetting nodes={
      for nodewalk={fake=r,L}{prepend={[0, red]},append={[1, red]}},
    }
  },
  []
}
```

and the second with

```
\Forest{
  my tree={
    before typesetting nodes={
      for nodewalk={fake=r,l}{replace by={[40, red, append, prepend={[,phantom]}]}}
    },
  },
  []
}
```

You could also name the nodes in your base tree for ease of reference or search by content etc, when making the modifications.

[image: three tree variations]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  my tree/.style={
    delay={
      !r.replace by={[4, #1 [5[15][9]][8[20][10]]]},
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\Forest{
  my tree,
  []
}
\Forest{
  my tree={
    before typesetting nodes={
      for nodewalk={fake=r,L}{prepend={[0, red]},append={[1, red]}},
    }
  },
  []
}
\Forest{
  my tree={
    before typesetting nodes={
      for nodewalk={fake=r,l}{replace by={[40, red, append, prepend={[,phantom]}]}}
    },
  },
  []
}
\end{document}
```